# AWS API Gateway CORS console enabled but still getting Response to preflight request doesn't pass ...No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, google-chrome, aws-api-gateway

I create an api from api gateway with a get and a put method, I have enabled the CORS from console and deployed the api, then generated javascript SDK.
In my codes I try to establish connection through apigClient.js connect keeps failling

```js
    var body = { };
    var params = {bucket: 'my-bucket-name', filename: 'my-image.jpg'};
    var additionalParams = {headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    'content-Type':"application/json"
    }};

    apigClient.bucketFilenameGet(params, body , additionalParams).then(function(res){
        console.log("connection successful")
        showImages(res.data)
      }).catch(function(result){
          console.log("connection failed")
      });
```

This is my method response it access through a lambda function and does not require api key
[image]

The lambda function access a S3 bucket, this is the bucket CORS permission
[image]

I'm able to use postman to perform both GET and PUT request, but when I try to initiate the api gateway from the above codes, I keep getting the error on chrome.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
'https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/my-bucket-name/my-image.jpg' 
from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I tried to use command to disable chrome's CORS and restart the browser but did not work

```bash
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --user-data-dir="/var/tmp/chrome-dev-disabled-security" --disable-web-security --disable-site-isolation-trials
```

Not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: Adding random headers to the client request will definitely trigger CORS preflights.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests

Answer (score 0):

"Preflight" in the error message is referring to the `/OPTIONS` method in APIGW.  Can you confirm that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` is also added to the Integration Response of your `/OPTIONS` method?

Also, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` isn't needed on the JS request.

A final troubleshooting note, if APIGW is hitting an error and returning a 4XX or 5XX response, you can also get a Preflight error.  To fix this, in APIGW, find Gateway Responses in the left-side menu and also add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` to Default 4XX and Default 5XX.